# ms-access: specifying formatting for a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i would like all data that is entered into a specific column to always have a trailing comma and also i need the first character to always be a comma. how do i do this? the best solution is probably not in vba or sql but probably the properties of the table?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to store multiple values in a single field. Please explain *why* you want to do this, and my guess it the problem will vanish. You're asking how to implement a particular solution, but not really describing the actual problem your solution is intended to address.

Comment: dave, in theory you are right, but practically speaking sometimes you need to use bandaids on a solution instead of a whole new solution, im sure you agree

Comment: First off, my name is not "Dave." Second, no, I don't agree at all. -1 for refusing to clarify a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider whether you actually need those leading and trailing commas stored in the table.  You can include them in a query whenever you need them.

```
SELECT
    some_text, 
    "," & some_text & "," AS with_commas, 
    IIf(Not IsNull(some_text), "," & some_text & ",", Null) AS with_commas_ignore_nulls
FROM YourTable;
```

If you really need the commas stored with the field, consider a form with a Before Update event to require the commas.

```
Private Sub txtsome_text_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Len(Me.txtsome_text & vbNullString) > 0 _
            And Not Me.txtsome_text Like ",*," Then
        MsgBox "some_text must start and end with a comma"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to apply a [Validation Rule](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA100963121033.aspx) or [Input Mask](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA100964521033.aspx) to that field of the table (in the Table Design View).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if the value meets the requirements and display an error if it doesn't then use a validation rule like VeeArr suggested.  If you want to correct the value if it doesn't meet the requirements then use a VBA event.

Comment: no i believe the way to go is through the format properties but i dont know how to use it

Comment: Unlikely. The Format property does not change how data is stored; only how it is displayed. Thus, it would not affect your ability to query against the data. (I'm assuming you want this to create a list of elements in one column of a table that can be searched using "%,id,%" (which is a bad idea, by the way). Using the Format property will NOT accomplish this.